# Json using ng-if to show in angularJs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following Json Data Generated from PHP API, I tried to make what i want to achieve in MYSQL Query and PHP Script. But Gets Too complicated.

```
 $data1 = [
        {
            "IDa": "6",
            "IDusr": "1",
            "doc_name": "name_doc.jpg",
            "doc_type": "doc"
        },
        {
            "IDa": "7",
            "IDusr": "1",
            "doc_name": "nameOne.jpg",
            "doc_type": "jpg"
        },
    ]

$data2 = [  
        {
            "IDa": "8",
            "IDusr": "1",
            "doc_name": "nameTwo.jpg",
            "doc_type": "jpg"
        },
        {
            "IDa": "9",
            "IDusr": "1",
            "doc_name": "nameThr.jpg",
            "doc_type": "jpg"
        },
        ]


$data3 = [      
        {
            "IDa": "10",
            "IDusr": "1",
            "doc_name": "nameOne_doc.jpg",
            "doc_type": "doc"
        },
        ]

$data4 = [      
        {
            "IDa": "11",
            "IDusr": "1",
            "doc_name": " ",
            "doc_type": "null"
        },
        ]
```

As you see there are four example products From the above json what i want to achieve is that,

```
From $data1 will be showen only IDa = 7
From $data2 will be showen  IDa = 8 and 9
From $data1 will be showen only IDa = 10
From $data1 will be showen only IDa = 11
```

how do I achieve that in Angular ng-if, if that is possible or not any other way in AngularJS?

Appreciate your help in advance...

Comment: what do you mean by `achieve grouping by "doc_type"`; do you mean sort?

Comment: not really, but grouping the whole data by doc_type. let me update the question so that you will see what out put i need.

Comment: are you really getting 4 different arrays from the server? and why are you naming your variables starting with `$`?

Comment: NOO, I am getting only one

Comment: but it comes in those Four forms

Comment: In short, those four probabilities are available. So the solution should work for all. That is what i meant.

Comment: I've read through your question multiple times, and the comments you have made on the question and the proposed answers, and I find it very difficult to understand what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Very simple, if in the Json data doc_type - jpg available hide the other doc_types, if not show doc_type DOC if Not show NULL Type? I wish if you Don't Vote Negaive also...If not clear ask me again...

Comment: and all the job should be done in AngularJS File...Give you example Mr @Claies look this example and try to show according to the above condition I have mentioned. http://plnkr.co/edit/fd9UGu?p=preview

Comment: so you just want a filter?

Comment: ya, may be..but Filter doesn't seems working...But try it and please let me know if it works for you....

Answer (score 1):

try this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fBgYoh?p=preview

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  console.log(images[i].doc_type);
  if(!sortedImages[ images[i].doc_type ]){
    sortedImages[images[i].doc_type] = [];
  }
  sortedImages[images[i].doc_type].push(images[i]);
}
```

[image]

output:

[image]

Comment: could you please see the question again, I have update it. so that it will be much easier to understand what i want to achive

Comment: i add you poiint...Please look the question again...Thanks

Comment: yes, this addresses your question just fine. What's the problem, that you need the variable names to specifically be `$data1`, `$data2` or something?

Comment: just to separate one json data from the other. and it seems your solution looks ok, I am checking on both solution so that i will accept as answer one of you.

Comment: can easily output the same thing in the nested `ng-repeat` angular view as with the for loop or with @manji's reduce. They both build the same dictionary object. Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/fd9UGu?p=preview

Comment: Ok, the ng-repeat is perfect, But the question is how do I show only jpg if available in the data, else the doc else the null??

Comment: means you can not show all together, If JPG available in DATA then only show jpg ignore the others. If Not JPG the DOC..IFNot Doc then of course the NULL one..

Comment: How do i achieve that??

Comment: you could just do it with ng-if on an element in the ng-repeat like `<div ng-if="v.doc_type == 'doc'">{{v.doc_name}}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

The following loops over all the items and fills a dictionary indexed by `doc_type`:

```
var res = $data.reduce(function(dict, item) {
  dict[item.doc_type] = (dict[item.doc_type] || []);
  dict[item.doc_type].push(item);
  return dict;
}, {});
```

Equivalent to:

```
var item,
    i,
    res = {};

for(var i = 0; i < $data.length; i++) {
  item = $data[i];
  if(!res[item.data_type]) {
    res[item.data_type] = [];
  }
  res[item.data_type].push(item);
}
```

### About angular's [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $data">
  <span ng-if="item.IDa === '6'">...</span>
</div>
```

The span, where the `ng-if` is applied, will be displayed only for the item with IDa = 6.

To check for multiple values:

```
<span ng-if="item.IDa === '6' || item.IDa === '7'">...</span>
```

```js
var $data = [
    {
        "IDa": "6",
        "IDusr": "1",
        "doc_name": "name_doc.jpg",
        "doc_type": "doc"
    },
    {
        "IDa": "7",
        "IDusr": "1",
        "doc_name": "nameOne.jpg",
        "doc_type": "jpg"
    },
    {
        "IDa": "8",
        "IDusr": "1",
        "doc_name": "nameTwo.jpg",
        "doc_type": "jpg"
    },
    {
        "IDa": "9",
        "IDusr": "1",
        "doc_name": "nameThr.jpg",
        "doc_type": "jpg"
    },
    {
        "IDa": "10",
        "IDusr": "1",
        "doc_name": "nameOne_doc.jpg",
        "doc_type": "doc"
    },
    {
        "IDa": "11",
        "IDusr": "1",
        "doc_name": " ",
        "doc_type": "null"
    },
];
  
var res = $data.reduce(function(dict, item) {
  dict[item.doc_type] = (dict[item.doc_type] || []);
  dict[item.doc_type].push(item);
  return dict;
}, {});

$('#result').text(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, could you please once again look at the question, i have updated it. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: You are correct, But I have explained and write down again..Please check the question again it is there.

Comment: Added an example of using `ng-if`.